# SQL Query - More options and suggestions apart from pivoting

Tags: sql

New to SQL please dont mind if this is a silly question..
My table looks like this

[image]

I want to send only one email to manager telling him that these employees in your group failed to fill timesheet.
currently i have pivoted the above table that looks like this 
and sending emails by concatinating firstemp+secondemp+thirdemp+------
can this be done in any more easiest way..?
[image]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: You probably want to explore what `GROUP BY` clause can do for you. See more here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CONCAT() function to retrieve a single row data in one column

```
SELECT M_EMAIL,
       CONCAT(FIRSTEMP, SECONDEMP, THIRDEMP, FOURTHEMP, FIFTHEMP...)
FROM 'your_table';
```

CONCAT() replaces NULL values with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't pivot, as the concat is really ugly to maintain (and will break if a more capable manager pops up with more subordinates than your concat columns).

The syntax depends on what SQL server you use. For example, in MSSQL you could do this:

```
select manager, m_email, STRING_AGG(employee, ', ') as subordinates
from Employee
group by manager, m_email
```

This result has only 1 row per manager and fixed number of columns regardless how many subordinates the manager has:

```
manager | m_email   | subordinates
----------------------------------
A       | A@A.COM   | b, D
D       | D@D.COM   | e, h
I       | I@I.COM   | j
```

Play with the example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/73bb5/5

Another option is just query relevant data to application layer and do the grouping there.

Comment: That would work on Postgres as well (it also has `string_agg()` - actually long before SQL Server did ;) )